# Insufficient Memory in Buffer Pool - Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a large query that writes to a custom table in my database. The databases I am calling on are about 6-7 million rows per table. The query includes join statements and sub-queries.

Previously when I have run this query, my raw data databases were significantly smaller. In the range of 1-2 million rows per table. Everything was working up until I imported more data... I've run into this error a few times prior to this addition of data and clearing the working memory cache's worked well

The host computer currently has 8GB of RAM. That computer is used solely for uploading data to the server and hosting the server. The laptop I am calling the commands from only has 4 GB of RAM.

1) Do I have enough memory on my server computer and my laptop? When I run a large query is it using the memory on my laptop or on my host computer? When answering, can you please explain how the working memory of the computer works in conjunction with SQL?

2) If I do not need to add memory, how do I configure my server to prevent this error from occurring?

```
Additional Information from Server Properties:
Indexing Memory Creation is set to 0 (Dynamic Memory)
Minimum memory per query = 1024 KB
Maximum server memory = maxed out @ 21474836447 MB
Minimum Server Memory = 10 MB
```

Comment: If the query produces no output and writes to the server the memory consumption should be on the server side. You should provide more information about the query and the database structure. You could also try to break down the query and write to the destination table with smaller junks.

Comment: Gerd, thanks for getting back to me. What type of information around would be helpful in determining the issue? The query is pretty beefy. there are 3 subqueries that have a join statement in each and outside the subqueries there are 4 other join statements. In the body of the select statement, there are a bunch of case statements that count conditions. . . . .